# How to use prior value in case statement or set variable in case statement in sql statement in function

Tags: postgresql

I'm using postgresql 10.4

The source data is derived from the following table

```
create table if not exists impressions
(
    id_impressions bigserial not null,
    date_visit timestamp not null,
    address_id integer not null,
    constraint impressions_pkey
    primary key (id_impressions)        
);

insert into impressions(date_visit, address_id)
values ('2018-06-01 15:36:47',1),
       ('2018-06-01 15:38:22',1),
       ('2018-06-01 15:38:22',1),
       ('2018-06-01 18:10:44',1),
       ('2018-06-01 00:05:21',17),
       ('2018-06-01 00:05:21',17),
       ('2018-06-01 00:10:57',17);
```

The next table is the location of the results

```
create table if not exists sessions
    (
        address_id integer,
        date_visit timestamp,
        session_id integer,
        impressions_id bigint,
        what_i_want_session_id uuid
    )
```

I have the following data

```
address_id date_visit session_id what_i_want_session_id

1   2018-06-01 15:36:47 1   7c8815fd-04ec-4f16-a467-d28ac7c9c1fd
1   2018-06-01 15:38:22 1   <null>
1   2018-06-01 15:38:22 1   <null>
1   2018-06-01 18:10:44 2   e6e2c427-0354-4017-8019-319e4b56358b
17  2018-06-01 00:05:21 3   7d0c1fe9-e229-4c1c-977b-2caaaa62624c
17  2018-06-01 00:05:21 3   <null>
17  2018-06-01 00:10:57 3   <null>
```

It needs to be like so:

address_id date_visit session_id what_i_want_session_id

```
1   2018-06-01 15:36:47 1   7c8815fd-04ec-4f16-a467-d28ac7c9c1fd
1   2018-06-01 15:38:22 1   7c8815fd-04ec-4f16-a467-d28ac7c9c1fd
1   2018-06-01 15:38:22 1   7c8815fd-04ec-4f16-a467-d28ac7c9c1fd
1   2018-06-01 18:10:44 2   e6e2c427-0354-4017-8019-319e4b56358b
17  2018-06-01 00:05:21 3   7d0c1fe9-e229-4c1c-977b-2caaaa62624c
17  2018-06-01 00:05:21 3   7d0c1fe9-e229-4c1c-977b-2caaaa62624c
17  2018-06-01 00:10:57 3   7d0c1fe9-e229-4c1c-977b-2caaaa62624c
```

I use the following query to create the aforementioned data. i'm including the second case statement as the example of what I'm trying to obtain in the final solution. The first case statement does lead to an accurate solution but I require that the session id never be used in again on subsequent runs. Setting a new uuid for a value is straight forward but I'm unsure how to replace the null values with the preceding uuid.

```
select address_id,
       s1.date_visit,
       sum(is_new_session) over (order by address_id, s1.date_visit) as   session_id,
       what_i_want_session_id
       from (
         select *,
         case when extract('EPOCH' from s0.date_visit) -
          extract('EPOCH' from last_event) >= 1800
          or last_event is null then 1
         else 0 end as is_new_session,
          (case when extract('EPOCH' from s0.date_visit) -
           extract('EPOCH' from last_event) >= 1800
           or last_event is null then gen_random_uuid() end) as what_i_want_session_id
              from (
                   select address_id,
                          i.date_visit,
                          lag(i.date_visit, 1) over (partition by address_id order by i.date_visit) AS last_event
                   from impressions i
                   where i.date_visit between '20180601' and '20180601'::date + interval '1 day'
                   ) s0
         ) s1;
```

Comment: Please edit you question an include the `CREATE TABLE` statement for the table and sample data as `INSERT INTO` statements with which you want to produce the desired output.

Comment: Edited as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way is using a CTE. We can then use a subquery to get the non null `what_i_want_session_id` using `session_id` as link.

```
WITH cte
AS
(
SELECT x.address_id,
       x.date_visit,
       sum(x.is_new_session) OVER (ORDER BY x.address_id,
                                            x.date_visit) session_id,
       CASE x.is_new_session
         WHEN 1 THEN
           gen_random_uuid()
       END what_i_want_session_id
       FROM (SELECT i.address_id,
                    i.date_visit,
                    CASE
                      WHEN coalesce(i.date_visit
                                    - lag(i.date_visit,
                                          1) OVER (PARTITION BY i.address_id
                                                   ORDER BY i.date_visit),
                                    '00:30:00'::interval) >= '00:30:00'::interval THEN
                        1
                      ELSE
                        0
                    END is_new_session
                    FROM impressions i) x
)
SELECT c1.address_id,
       c1.date_visit,
       c1.session_id,
       (SELECT c2.what_i_want_session_id
               FROM cte c2
               WHERE c2.session_id = c1.session_id
                     AND c2.what_i_want_session_id IS NOT NULL) what_i_want_session_id
FROM cte c1;
```

For a CTE-less solution we need to get the distinct `session_id`s and get a random value for each one. We can then join this again using `session_id` as link.

```
SELECT x5.address_id,
       x5.date_visit,
       x5.session_id,
       x4.what_i_want_session_id
       FROM (SELECT x3.session_id,
                    gen_random_uuid() what_i_want_session_id
                    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
                                 x2.session_id
                                 FROM (SELECT sum(x1.is_new_session) OVER (ORDER BY x1.address_id,
                                                                                    x1.date_visit) session_id
                                              FROM (SELECT i.address_id,
                                                           i.date_visit,
                                                           CASE
                                                             WHEN coalesce(i.date_visit
                                                                           - lag(i.date_visit,
                                                                                 1) OVER (PARTITION BY i.address_id
                                                                                          ORDER BY i.date_visit),
                                                                           '00:30:00'::interval) >= '00:30:00'::interval THEN
                                                               1
                                                             ELSE
                                                               0
                                                           END is_new_session
                                                           FROM impressions i) x1) x2) x3) x4
            INNER JOIN (SELECT x1.address_id,
                               x1.date_visit,
                               sum(x1.is_new_session) OVER (ORDER BY x1.address_id,
                                                                     x1.date_visit) session_id
                               FROM (SELECT i.address_id,
                                            i.date_visit,
                                            CASE
                                              WHEN coalesce(i.date_visit
                                                            - lag(i.date_visit,
                                                                  1) OVER (PARTITION BY i.address_id
                                                                           ORDER BY i.date_visit),
                                                            '00:30:00'::interval) >= '00:30:00'::interval THEN
                                                1
                                              ELSE
                                                0
                                            END is_new_session
                                            FROM impressions i) x1) x5
                       ON x5.session_id = x4.session_id;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=6533443c95901ec87b5d5837e1dbb7e8)

Note: In the fiddle the extension for the `gen_random_uuid()` function is missing, so I used `random()` there instead.

Comment: Thank you very much this works perfectly. The non-cte version is light years faster than the cte. I tried running an explain analyze on it and it ran so long I gave up and aborted it. The non-cte version completes in about 7 seconds. I don't really care why the cte version is slower so I won't be investigating it further the other version is more than adequate :-)